# Codeanywhere updated HTML issues

Tags: html, css, ide, codeanywhere

So I'm using Codeanywhere and when I load the HTML page I'm working on in the browser, it won't show my new changes.

For example I'll change a word in the index.html and when I go to the page it won't reflect said change.

I've cleared the cashe, and hard reset the page multiple times, I've also updated chrome and opened the page in a different browser, still to no avail.

Does anyone have any further solutions?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can try the following solutions:

1.Force Refresh

2.Check File Paths

3.Restart the Server

4.Use Incognito Mode